# How to stop endless EJB 3 timer?

Tags: java, timer, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am new to EJB 3 . I use the following code to start endless EJB 3 timer
 then deploying it on JBOSS 4.2.3

```
@Stateless
public class SimpleBean  implements SimpleBeanRemote,TimerService  {

@Resource
TimerService timerService;
private Timer timer ;
@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("Hello EJB");

 }
}
```

then calling it

```
  timer = timerService.createTimer(10,  5000, null);
```

It works well. I created a client class that calls a method that creates the timer and a method that is called when the timer times out.

I forget to call cancel 
then it does not stop .redeploy with cancel call never stop it. restart Jboss 4.2.3 never stop it. How I can stop EJB timer ?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put the `stop()` method into your bean and call it with your **timer name** as a parameter. It will iterate over all timers and will stop your timer.

```
public void stop(String timerName) {
    for(Object obj : timerService.getTimers()) {
        Timer t = (Timer)obj;
        if (t.getInfo().equals(timerName)) {
            t.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After three years, Thanks A lot :)

Comment: This cancels all the timers, but if you consult the "getTimers()" they still there :/

Comment: No! This will cancel only the timers that have the same name as `timerName`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, with my JBoss AS 6.1.
After killing this endless (persistent) timers I found the following solution for AVOIDING this
problem in the future:
With JBoss AS 6.1 (EJB 3.1) it is possible to create non-persistent automatic timers, they DO NOT SURVIVE a server restart:

```
@Schedule(minute=”*/10”, hour=”*”, persistent=false)
public void automaticTimeout () {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also undeploy your application, this will "kill" all timers.

Comment: Not likely if the timers are persistent

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to creat ethe automatic timer (@Schedule) with the 'info' attribute and then check in the timer service for timers with the same info and if available cancel it:

```
@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*",second="3", persistent=false,info="AUTO_TIMER_0")
void automaticTimeOut(){

    if(timerCount==0){System.out.println("FROM AUTOMATIC TIME OUT -----------------> CALLED");timerCount++;}
    else{

        Iterator<Timer> timerIterator=timerService.getTimers().iterator();

        Timer timerToCancel=null;
        while(timerIterator.hasNext()){

            Timer tmpTimer=timerIterator.next();
            if(tmpTimer.getInfo().equals("AUTO_TIMER_0")){timerToCancel=tmpTimer;break;}

        }//while closing

        if(timerToCancel!=null){

            timerToCancel.cancel();
            System.out.println("AUTOMATIC TIMER HAS BEEN CANCELED ----------------->>>>");

        }//if closing

    }//else closing

}//automaticTimeOut closing
```

Answer (score 1):

Since EJB 3.1, there are new methods on `TimerService` which take a `TimerConfig` instead of a `Serializable` payload. Using `TimerConfig` allows to make the `Timer` non-persistent.

```
timerService.createIntervalTimer(10, 5000, new TimerConfig(null, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `@PreDestroy` annotation within the bean where you want to close.

For example:

```
@PreDestroy
private void undeployTimer() {
 //..
}
```

Generally the resource de-allocation is done here.